# Can I append a "megadump" to the default ColdFusion error page?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I wish to toggle friendly error messaging in ColdFusion 9. My app.cfm looks like:

```
<cfset App.EnableDebug = true>
<CFERROR TYPE="VALIDATION" TEMPLATE="/errorhandler.cfm"> 
<CFERROR TYPE="EXCEPTION" TEMPLATE="/errorhandler.cfm">
<CFERROR TYPE="REQUEST" TEMPLATE="/errorhandler.cfm">
```

Currently, my errorhandler.cfm looks at App.EnableDebug and either displays a friendly error message or a cfdump of the error variable and then a "megadump" of all defined variables (app, cgi, session, etc). My problem is we prefer the look/layout of the default error page provided by ColdFusion. However, we also like having the "megadump" of all our variables.

Now, I know that if I just comment out the cferror tags then ColdFusion will display it's default error page. Which is pretty handy, except I wish to include a "megadump" of all my variables. Any way to merge my two desires into one reality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default error handler is just a CFM file.  You can edit it, or replace it with whatever you like.

This file is located in the server instance's WEB-INF/exception folder.  The file name is detail.cfm

Answer (score 0):

You prefer the look of the default error page?  Do as Sean suggests, or,

1. throw an error
2. save the error page from your browser as errorhandler.cfm
3. insert your cfdump etc

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sean Coyne's answer, except a little more safe is to make a copy of detail.cfm and place it in your webroot as error.cfm.  Then you can use the cferror tag just like you had before and in error.cfm just add your dumps.

Again the detail.cfm page is in {CFWebRoot}/WEB-INF/exception/.